# Sum Values in a Dictionary w/ respect to the Key - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

My dictionary `Dict` is arranged as follows. Each key is associated with a list of values, where each value is a tuple:

```
Dict = { 
    'key1': [('Red','Large',30),('Red','Medium',40),('Blue','Small',45)],
    'key2': [('Red','Large',35)],
    'key3': [('Yellow','Large',30),('Red','Medium',30)], 
}
```

I then want to sum the integers (index 2 of each tuple) given a new key, Color in this case.

The resulting new dictionary should look something like:

```
{
    'key1': [('Red', 70), ('Blue', 45)],
    'key2': [('Red', 35)],
    'key3': [('Yellow', 30), ('Red', 30)],
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

I was thinking something like the following, but I know this is wrong in several ways.

```
sum = 0
new_dict = {}
new_key = raw_input("Enter a new key to search on: ")
for k,v in Dict:
  if v[0] == new_key:
    sum = sum + v[2]
    new_dict[k].append(sum)
  else:
    sum = 0
    new_dict[k] = [sum]
```

Comment: sorry, typo. that should be Dict. my original Dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension to produce your new output:

```
{key: [color, sum(t[2] for t in value if t[0] == color)] for key, value in Dict.iteritems()}
```

where `color` is the key to search on.

Demo:

```
>>> Dict = {
...     'key1': [('Red','Large',30),('Red','Medium',40),('Blue','Small',45)],
...     'key2': [('Red','Large',35)],
...     'key3': [('Yellow','Large',30),('Red','Medium',30)], 
... }
>>> color = 'Red'
>>> {key: [color, sum(t[2] for t in value if t[0] == color)] for key, value in Dict.iteritems()}
{'key3': ['Red', 30], 'key2': ['Red', 35], 'key1': ['Red', 70]}
```

To sum *all* values by color, use a `Counter()` to sum the values:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

new_dict = {}
for key, values in Dict.iteritems():
    counts = Counter()
    for color, _, count in values:
        counts[color] += count
    new_dict[key] = counts.items()
```

which gives:

```
>>> new_dict = {}
>>> for key, values in Dict.iteritems():
...     counts = Counter()
...     for color, _, count in values:
...         counts[color] += count
...     new_dict[key] = counts.items()
... 
>>> new_dict
{'key3': [('Red', 30), ('Yellow', 30)], 'key2': [('Red', 35)], 'key1': [('Blue', 45), ('Red', 70)]}
```

Comment: Thanks. that really helps. What if I didnt specify the color, and want to just sum everything that has the same color for a given key?  Please see my edit above to my expected results.

Comment: @brno792: Your output for the second element makes no sense; it should be `[('Red', 35)]`, a tuple in a list.

Comment: Sorry, left out the tuple by mistake. its fixed now. So how to do this without specifying the Color?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  I have one other small issue. So the amounts that I'm summing are actually stored as strings in my original dictionary, so I cant += them.  How can I cast that value as a float or double? Where in my code should i do that, when creating my new_dict or earlier?

Comment: @brno792: Just use `counts[color] += float(value)` then.